# How to store multi selection in SceneStorage using NavigationLink in NavigationSplitView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Let's work our way up to the problem in code.

**BASE**

```
struct Animal: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

//REQUIRED FOR USE IN SCENESTORAGE
extension Set: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public typealias RawValue = String
    
    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return string
    }
    
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = Set(result)
    }
}
```

**1. WORKS**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sampleData = [
        Animal(name: "Bird"),
        Animal(name: "Cat"),
        Animal(name: "Dog"),
        Animal(name: "Fish")
    ]
    
    @State
    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
//    @SceneStorage("multiSelection")
//    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(sampleData, selection: $multiSelection) { animal in
                Text(animal.name)
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

**2. WORKS**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sampleData = [
        Animal(name: "Bird"),
        Animal(name: "Cat"),
        Animal(name: "Dog"),
        Animal(name: "Fish")
    ]
    
//    @State
//    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
    @SceneStorage("multiSelection")
    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(sampleData, selection: $multiSelection) { animal in
                Text(animal.name)
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

**3. WORKS**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sampleData = [
        Animal(name: "Bird"),
        Animal(name: "Cat"),
        Animal(name: "Dog"),
        Animal(name: "Fish")
    ]
    
    @State
    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
//    @SceneStorage("multiSelection")
//    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(sampleData, selection: $multiSelection) { animal in
                NavigationLink(animal.name, value: animal.id)
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

**4. BREAKS**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sampleData = [
        Animal(name: "Bird"),
        Animal(name: "Cat"),
        Animal(name: "Dog"),
        Animal(name: "Fish")
    ]
    
//    @State
//    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
    @SceneStorage("multiSelection")
    private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(sampleData, selection: $multiSelection) { animal in
                NavigationLink(animal.name, value: animal.id)
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see, other then a bug, why this wouldn't work. The expect behavior is that we can select the items and they stay selected. However, now the item is directly unselected as if it is not able to store.

How can we store this multiselection in SceneStorage so we can restore it?

Comment: Selection of link means immediate navigation, how do you imagine multiple-selection functionality of this? Or did I miss anything?

Comment: By the way, 3 and 4 work the same for me, Xcode 14b3 / iPadOS 16 Simulator / macOS 12.4. Would you demo some screen recordings of differences in your scenario.

Comment: `SceneStorage` is not guaranteed to work at all https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenestorage . It is a nice to have feature but your app should not depend on it.

Comment: @Asperi no you are not missing anything. That actually makes sense haha. I do like to support multi selection to delete multiple entries at once, but I guess regarding storing only one identifier makes sense so a different var.

Comment: @Asperi for the completeness I will do some screen recording.

Comment: @loremipsum SceneStorage is very strange indeed, but sometimes it does restore the windows and then it has no data in it. So that's why I was in need for SceneStorage, but I guess I have to look at it some other way. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The Animals are being init with different UUIDs every app launch, so the restored selected UUIDs cannot be found, one way to fix it is:

```
struct Animal: Identifiable {
    let name: String       
    var id: String { name }
}
```

Also, it is preferable to do:

```
@SceneStorage("multiSelection")
private var multiSelection: Set<Animal.ID> = []
```